# 'seen' message status on Facebook website and Messenger app

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Some of the messages I have sent to Facebook friends are appearing with 'seen' stamp if I open the messages on facebook.com while they are unseen on the Messenger app. Which one is the right one? It seems to me that messenger is right because on Facebook, all the times when the message is seen is one minute after sending the message.

Comment: Update the Messenger app and check if you see the difference.

Comment: Yes, already did that. No difference!

Comment: Okay, I reinstalled Messenger and logged in again and it works now. So, messenger was right anyways earlier but it was the website that was screwing up. But now they are interfaced correctly, it seems. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, you take the beans. Thank me :)

Comment: Oh no, I just saw that you were the first commenter. Sorry, I thought someone just added this answer

Comment: So, you deserve the beans :)

Comment: Don't worry. I have submitted that as _community wikki_ answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalled Messenger and logged in again and it should work.